# How to create a BufReader for an openssl::ssl::SslStream?

Tags: rust, openssl

I try to create a BufReader from my application.
It works fine for TcpStream but I saw no way to do it for a SslStream.

I tried:

```
 self.buf_reader = Some(BufReader::new(
     self.ssl_stream.as_ref().unwrap().get_ref().unwrap(),
 ));
```

With:

```
    ssl_stream: Option<SslStream<TcpStream>>,
    buf_reader: Option<BufReader<TcpStream>>,
```

But while reading fro the buffer, the data are obviously still encrypted (because it clones the underlying stream but not the SslStream).

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just be able to do this:

```rust
BufReader::new(ssl_stream.unwrap())
```

EDIT: Here's a complete example.

```rust
use openssl::ssl::SslStream;
use std::net::TcpStream;
use std::io::BufReader;

struct Test {
    ssl_stream: Option<SslStream<TcpStream>>,
    buf_reader: Option<BufReader<SslStream<TcpStream>>>,
}

impl Test {
    fn test(&mut self) {
        if let Some(s) = self.ssl_stream.take() {
            self.buf_reader = Some(BufReader::new(s));
        }
    }
}
```

Another point of note is that BufReader will consume the SslStream.  In the example above, I use `take()` to move the stream instead of trying to use a reference.

Comment: Thank you @Sean. I tried that: `self.buf_reader = Some(BufReader::new(self.ssl_stream.as_mut().unwrap()));`
But I have the error below: `
mismatched types

expected struct 'openssl::ssl::SslStream', found mutable reference
note:         expected struct 'openssl::ssl::SslStream<std::net::TcpStream>'
      found mutable reference '&mut openssl::ssl::SslStream<std::net::TcpStream>'rustc(E0308)
mod.rs(431, 47): expected struct 'openssl::ssl::SslStream', found mutable reference
`
I need to pass the ReadBuff into that struct so it is available for further calls to functions.